# Is this a viable approach to a Promise implementation

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to write my own Promises/A+ compliant promise implementation.

Below is a second (incomplete) attempt.

Does this look like an implementation that will continue to be viable as I develop it further?

```js
const uninitializedToPending = p=>{
    p['__status__'] = 'pending';
    p['__isResolved__'] = false;
}

const pendingToFulfilled = (p,result)=>{
    p['__status__'] = 'fulfilled';
    p['__isResolved__'] = true;
    p['__result__'] = result;
}

const pendingToRejected = (p,reason)=>{
    p['__status__'] = 'rejected';
    p['__isResolved__'] = true;
    p['__result__'] = reason;
}

const go = async(function(thens, result) {
    while (thens.length) {
        thens.pop()(result);
    }
});

function async(cb) {
    return (...args)=>setTimeout(()=>cb(...args));
}

var id = 0;

function Promise(executor=()=>{}) {
    const thens = []
      , catches = [];

    const p = {
        id: ++id,
        then,
        catch: ccatch,
        resolve,
        reject,
    };

    uninitializedToPending(p);
    executor(resolve, reject);
    return p;

    function resolve(result) {
        pendingToFulfilled(p, result);
        go(thens, result);
    }

    function reject(reason) {
        pendingToRejected(p, reason);
        go(catches, reason);
    }

    function then(cb) {
        const p2 = new Promise();
        thens.unshift(result=>{
            const result2 = cb(result);
            if (result2 && result2.then) {
                p2['__isResolved__'] = true;
                result2.then((result)=>{
                    p2.resolve(result);
                    return result;
                }
                );
                return;
            }
            p2.resolve(result2)
        }
        );
        return p2;
    }

    function ccatch(cb) {
        const p2 = new Promise();
        catches.unshift(reason=>{
            cb(reason);
            p2.reject(reason);
        }
        );
        return p2;
    }
}

// "Tests"
const p = new Promise(() => {}); // unresolved, pending
const q = new Promise(resolve => resolve('foo')); // resolved, fulfilled, value: foo
const r = new Promise((_,reject) => reject('foo')); // resolved, rejected, reason: foo
const s = new Promise(resolve => resolve('foo')).then(result => result + ' foo'); // resolved, fulfilled, value: "foo foo"
const t = new Promise(resolve => resolve('foo')).then(result => result + ' foo').then(result => result + ' foo'); // resolved, fulfilled, value: "foo foo foo"
const u = new Promise(resolve => resolve('foo')).then(result => new Promise(resolve => resolve(result + ' foo'))); // resolved, fulfilled, value: "foo foo"
const v = new Promise(resolve => resolve('foo')).then(result => new Promise(resolve => resolve(result + ' foo')).then(result => result + ' foo')); // resolved, fulfilled, value: "foo foo foo"
const w = new Promise(resolve=>resolve('foo'));
// branching:
w.then(result=>'a').then(console.log);
w.then(result=>'b').then(console.log);
```

Comment: It still lacks so much, but yeah you might use this as a basis. Start with giving `then` a second parameter "onrejected", and drop `catch` from your  constructor - implement it in terms of `then`.